# mysql - Select an "item" from a table and its specific "properties" from another table

Tags: mysql

I have a list of items and I'm trying to retrieve all of their properties. Some properties are common to all items and are defined in a `Product` table, the other properties are specific to each type of item and are inserted into a dedicated table per type of item.

The tables look like this :

```
mysql> select * from Product;
+----+--------+-------+----------+------+
| id | name   | price | quantity | type |
+----+--------+-------+----------+------+
|  1 | Book1  |    10 |       20 |    1 |
|  2 | Book2  |    20 |       30 |    1 |
|  3 | Books3 |    18 |       20 |    1 |
|  4 | Car1   |   150 |       10 |    2 |
|  5 | Car2   |   180 |       30 |    2 |
|  6 | Car3   |   170 |       10 |    2 |
+----+--------+-------+----------+------+

mysql> select * from Product_Book;
+----+------------+---------+--------+
| id | product_id | author  | title  |
+----+------------+---------+--------+
|  1 |          1 | Author1 | Title1 |
|  2 |          2 | Author2 | Title2 |
|  3 |          3 | Author3 | Title3 |
+----+------------+---------+--------+

mysql> select * from Product_Car;
+----+------------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | product_id | doors | color | make  |
+----+------------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |          4 |     4 | red   | make1 |
|  2 |          5 |     4 | blue  | make2 |
|  3 |          6 |     2 | black | make3 |
+----+------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

How can I select all items with all of their properties, based on the `Product.type` ?

I've tried with a CASE in the SELECT, but not very efficient :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Product.id,
    (CASE Product.type
        WHEN 1 THEN Product_Book.author
    END) as book_author,
    (CASE Product.type
        WHEN 2 THEN Product_Car.color
    END) as car_color
FROM
    Product,
    Product_Car,
    Product_Book
WHERE
    Product.id = Product_Book.product_id or
    Product.id = Product_Car.product_id
ORDER BY Product.id; 

+----+-------------+-----------+
| id | book_author | car_color |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  1 | Author1     | NULL      |
|  2 | Author2     | NULL      |
|  3 | Author3     | NULL      |
|  4 | NULL        | red       |
|  5 | NULL        | blue      |
|  6 | NULL        | black     |
+----+-------------+-----------+
```

Should I use a CASE in the FROM clause ? Is there a generic pattern for that case ? Is it possible to group specific item properties into an `extra` column which would contain the specific properties like ?

```
+----+--------+-------+----------+------+-------+
| id | name   | price | quantity | type | extra |
+----+--------+-------+----------+------+-------+
```

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at join sql clause. Your query should look like: select * from T1 left join T2 on T1.id=T2.sub_id; join.http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/join.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi as i suggested you in a comment you must use join clause.

```
select distinct * from Product 
left join Product_Book on Product.id=Product_Book.product_id
left join Product_Car on Product.id=Product_Car.product_id
```

Try it and give me feedback.

Comment: Testing with your reply, I got the all the values but with duplicated columns. So modifying it to get only the specific columns seems to do the trick :

`SELECT
    Product.id,
    Product.name,
    Product.quantity,
    Product.price,
    Product_Book.author,
    Product_Book.title,
    Product_Car.doors,
    Product_Car.make,
    Product_Car.color
FROM
    Product
LEFT JOIN Product_Book ON Product_Book.product_id = Product.id
LEFT JOIN Product_Car ON Product_Car.product_id = Product.id;`

Thanks.